# Setting static method as action of UITapGestureRecognizer in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a `UIView` programmatically in static method and want to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` which will call another static method in my `Helper` class.

**Helper.swift** :

```
static func showLoadingPopUp(frame: CGRect) -> UIView {
  let transView = UIView.init(frame: frame!)       
  let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "transViewTapped:")
  transView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
  return transView
}

static func transViewTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  print("Oh Tapped!!!")
}
```

But it ends up with the following message probably because of the static nature of my method. Also `Helper.swift` is simple swift class (not `UIView` or `UIViewController`)

**Error:**

> Unrecognized selector +[JaClassified.Helper transViewTapped:]

Comment: what version of swift are you using?

Comment: `swift 2.0` @Cheng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your class is not a descendant of `NSObject`, you may need to bridge the `static func` to Objective-C (since old style Objective-C selector works on `NSObject`s).

So, in your case, you could either declare you `Helper` class as

```
class Helper: NSObject {
    ...
}
```

or, you can bridge your `transViewTapped:` to Objective-C by prefix it with an `@objc`

```
@objc static func transViewTapped(gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    ...
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This didn't work for me — I still get "unrecognised selector" error. I'm registering the selector with notification center as follows:  NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(LocationTracker.instance, selector: #selector(orient), name: Notification.Name.UIDeviceOrientationDidChange, object: nil). orient() is a static method. LocationTracker inherits from NSObject. Anything wrong I'm doing?